# How do I solve urlpatterns problem in django?

Tags: python, django, url-pattern, loginview

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView, name='login', kwargs={
        'template_name': 'accounts/login_form.html',
    }),
    url(r'^logout/$', LogoutView, name='logout', kwargs={
        'next_page': 'login',
    }),
    url(r'^signup/$', views.signup, name='signup'),
    url(r'^signup/$', views.signup, name='signup'),
    url(r'^profile/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLKVZ.png)

Hello I've read through other posts regarding this error and I thought I solved the problem, but I'm still having trouble.

Comment: You don't have the url you are visiting in any of your patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('/my/url', views.MyViewFunction, name='my_url_name'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no url such as `accounts/login_form`. Perhaps you should go to `accounts/login`, use `name='login'`. You should also consider using `path('url_here', function, name=name_here)` instead of the old url.